# ExtJS4 grid won't update remote database

Tags: extjs, grid, store, extjs4

For some reason, this configuration of an ExtJS4 grid won't update. When you click on a cell, change a value, it hits the create URL, not the update URL, as defined in the proxy and observed with Firebug in FF4. Strangely, the datachanged event fires after loading the store when the page starts, but not after data has actually changed. Also, the grid send all rows to the create URL.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
Ext.onReady(function() {

    Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = '/images/extjs4/s.gif';
    Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();
    //Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));

    Ext.define('VendorError', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            {name: 'UnexpSrvID', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'VendorID', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'VendorName', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'VndActID', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'VndActNb', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'InvoiceID', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'VInvNb', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'VInvRcptDt', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d' },
            {name: 'InvDate', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d' },
            {name: 'CodeSpecifier', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'Recurrence', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'ClientID', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'ClientName', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'LocID', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'LocName', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'RecentLocStatus', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'RecentLocStatusDate', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d' },
            {name: 'UnexpCost', type: 'float'},
            {name: 'ConfirmedAmt', type: 'float'},
            {name: 'StaffID', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'NetworkID', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'UnexpStatCode', type: 'string'}
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            simpleSortMode: true,
            api: {
                read: '/internal/viewVERext_json.asp',
                create: '/internal/viewVERext_create.asp',
                update: '/internal/viewVERext_update.asp',
                destroy: '/internal/viewVERext_destroy.asp'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                totalProperty: 'total',
                successProperty: 'success',
                messageProperty: 'message',
                root: 'data'
            },
            writer: {
                type: 'json',
                writeAllFields: false,
                allowSingle: false,
                root: 'data'
            },
            listeners: {
                exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                    Ext.MessageBox.show({
                        title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                        msg: operation.getError(),
                        icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                        buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'VendorError',
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        pageSize: 20,
        remoteSort: true,
        listeners: {
        //  write: function(proxy, operation){
        //      if (operation.action == 'destroy') {
        //          main.child('#form').setActiveRecord(null);
        //      }
        //      Ext.example.msg(operation.action, operation.resultSet.message);
        //  }
            datachanged: function() {
                var report = "";
                store.each( 
                    function(rec) { 
                        report = report + rec.dirty + '/';
                    } 
                )
                alert(report);
            }
        }
    });

    // create the Grid
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        //stateful: true,
        //stateId: 'stateGrid',
        columns: [
            {   text     : 'Vendor',
                dataIndex: 'VendorName',
                flex     : 1
            },
            {   text     : 'Account',
                dataIndex: 'VndActNb'
            },
            {   text     : 'Invoice',
                dataIndex: 'VInvNb'
            },
            {   text     : 'Invoiced',
                dataIndex: 'InvDate', 
                xtype    : 'datecolumn',
                align    : 'center'
            },
            {   text     : 'Receipted',
                dataIndex: 'VInvRcptDt', 
                xtype    : 'datecolumn',
                align    : 'center'
            },
            {   text     : 'Description',
                dataIndex: 'CodeSpecifier'
            },
            {   text     : 'Client',
                dataIndex: 'ClientName'
            },
            {   text     : 'Location',
                dataIndex: 'LocName'
            },
            {   text     : 'LStatus',
                dataIndex: 'RecentLocStatus',
                align    : 'center'
            },
            {   text     : 'Credit',
                dataIndex: 'UnexpCost',
                tdCls    : 'colyellow',
                renderer : Ext.util.Format.usMoney,
                align    : 'right',
                field    : { xtype:'textfield', allowBlank:false }
            },
            {   text     : 'Confirmed',
                dataIndex: 'ConfirmedAmt',
                tdCls    : 'colyellow',
                renderer : Ext.util.Format.usMoney,
                align    : 'right',
                field    : { xtype:'textfield', allowBlank:false }
            },
            {   text     : 'Recurrence',
                dataIndex: 'Recurrence',
                tdCls    : 'colyellow',
                align    : 'center',
                field    : {
                    xtype    : 'combobox',
                    typeAhead: true,
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    selectOnTab: true,
                    store: [
                        ['once','once'],['1st','1st'],['2nd+','2nd+']
                    ],
                    lazyRender: true
                }
            },
            {   text     : 'CStatus',
                dataIndex: 'UnexpStatCode',
                tdCls    : 'colyellow',
                align    : 'center',
                field    : {
                    xtype    : 'combobox',
                    typeAhead: true,
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    selectOnTab: true,
                    store: [
                        <%=cstat_grid%>
                    ],
                    lazyRender: true
                }
            },
            {   text     : 'Owner',
                dataIndex: 'NetworkID',
                tdCls    : 'colyellow',
                field    : {
                    xtype    : 'combobox',
                    typeAhead: true,
                    triggerAction: 'all',
                    selectOnTab: true,
                    store: [
                        <%=staff_grid%>
                    ],
                    lazyRender: true
                }
            }
        ],
        layout: 'fit',
        height: 500,
        renderTo: 'theGrid',
        selType: 'cellmodel',
        plugins: [
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                clicksToEdit: 1
            })
        ],
        dockedItems: [
            {   xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                store: store,
                dock: 'bottom',
                displayInfo: true
            },
            {   xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                items: [
                    { xtype:'button', 
                      text: 'IsDirty()', 
                      handler: function() { 
                        var report = "";
                        store.each( 
                            function(rec) { 
                                report = report + rec.dirty + '/';
                            } 
                        )
                        alert(report);
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        viewConfig: {
            stripeRows: true
        }
    });

    Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(grid.doLayout, grid);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the issue is that records added into the grid are detected as "not new" by the value of a unique id field. A kind [poster](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134897-Grid-cell-update-POSTs-whole-grid) on the Sencha forums pointed me to this.

By default, this field in the model is expected to have a name of 'id'. So, you must either provide a model with a field of 'id', which my model above did not have, or you must override the default column by using the idProperty property of [Ext.data.Model](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Model). I simply renamed the `UnexpSrvId` column to `id`. And, lo and behold, we send updates to update() instead of create().

This is not obvious from the API docs, as many things unfortunately are in this powerful framework.

Answer (score 0):

Because your grid is using the `CellEdit` mixin you can add a listener to the `grid` which will commit the changes to your record after editing. So in your grid, add the listeners config option defined as follows...

```
listeners: {
    edit : function(e) {
        e.record.commit();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I think you're using the wrong syntax on your proxy... you can only define a reader and writer (by the looks of things)...

[Ed Spencer's article on Proxies](http://edspencer.net/2011/02/proxies-extjs-4.html)

[ExtJS 4 API Entry on Proxies](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy)

Comment: "Because your grid is using the CellEdit mixin" So, using the plugin results in an update to a single cell firing the create (instead of the update) on the proxy and sending all rows to it? That seems very wrong. Also, the issue isn't that there's nothing going to the server, but rather that all 20 rows get sent to the create URL!

Comment: I'm just downloading ExtJS 4 to my machine now, I'll have a play around because I'm not convinced this is the answer... my apologies if its not

Comment: No problem! Your time is most appreciated.

Comment: Actually, it's an Ajax proxy, which has an 'api' property that allows more specificity. http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax

Comment: Hmm, didn't see this in the search in the docs. I'm still a little unfamiliar with ExtJS 4... so my apologies

Comment: @alphadogg What happens if you have inline data (i.e., data that isn't coming from the server)? Does it still hit the create url? Also, each of your records in the grid, are they marked as phantom records? You can check this by using fire bug to inspect each record in your store (they should not have a phantom property)